# How to test socket.io events being called with sinon.spy

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mocha.js, sinon

First of all, I'm trying to test the second time a function being called returns the correct value. To be more specific, I'm trying to test the second time an event is received by socket.on() returns the correct value.

I know that Sinon.spy() can detect whether a function being called or not. But it seems not working with socket.io events.

I'm trying to test for example,

```
var socketio = io.connect(someUrl);
socketio.on(eventName, cb);
```

if the 'eventName' is called. I tried

```
var spy = sinon.spy(socketio, 'on');
assert(spy.withArgs(eventName).called);
```

But it says it's never being called.

Furthermore, what if I'd like to test the data in the callback function is right or not, for example

```
var socketio = io.connect(someUrl);
socketio.on(eventName, function(data) {
    data.should.equal(something);
});
```

Is it possible to test that?

***Update:***

I solved the problem by adding a count in callback

```
var count = 0;
socketio.on(eventName, function(data) {
    count++;
    if(count === 2) {
        data.should.equal(something)
    }
}
```

But I think this is a hacky way, is there any standard/smart way to do it(if possible using sinon)?

Comment: Is there a typo in your connect example? spy's dont have the method `withArg` - should be `withArgs`

Comment: @TristanHessell sorry it's a typo

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to spy on `on` -- that's only called once, at the time you set up the listener. (Unless you actually want to spy to see if the listeners are being set up at all, and don't care if they're actually used. That doesn't appear to be what you want here.)

Instead, you want to spy on the `cb` callback function, to see if and how it runs.

```
var callbackSpy = sinon.spy(cb);
```

Then, pass that spy in as the callback:

```
socketio.on(eventName, callbackSpy);
```

And test if the callback was ever run with the desired argument value:

```
assert(callbackSpy.calledWith(something));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clears my confusion about sinon.spy. But how should I test if the callback being called twice and receive the correct data the second time being called?

Comment: @Keming See http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/spies/ You can do `callbackSpy.getCall(1).args[0] === something` to test the first argument of the second (index `1`) call